# problems with routes in areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an area called Advert. This area as two route rules. But unfortunately only one of the route rules works at a time. Usually the first rule the other below would not work. but if I interswitch rules the one that comes first would work.

I would paste the rule and html links that call the rules.

Code snippet from AdvertAreaRegistration.cs

```
       public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {


               context.MapRoute(
       "Advert_second",
       "Advert/{controller}/{action}",
       new { controller = "AdvertAdmin", action = "Index" },
       namespaces: new string[] { "LiveChatPrototype.Mvc.Areas.Advert.Controllers" }
   );


        context.MapRoute(
           name: "Advert_default",
            url: "Advert/{id}/{advertid}",
            defaults: new {  controller = "Advertisement", action = "Index", id =UrlParameter.Optional, advertid = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new string[] { "LiveChatPrototype.Mvc.Areas.Advert.Controllers" }
        );


}
```

The html links which I use to call my rules

This is for the first rule.

This is for the second rule.

Either of the links would work if it rule comes first.

Please how can I make both rules work at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the two route segments are identical

**"Advert/{controller}/{action}"**

**"Advert/{id}/{advertid}"**

Both have two dynamic segments, so asp.net mvc cannot distinguish between the two and matches the first one.

But it seems like the segments in **"Advert/{id}/{advertid}"** **id** and **advertid** are intended to be integers. Then you can add regex constraint in the route to distinguish between them.
like

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        name: "Advert_default",
        url: "Advert/{id}/{advertid}",
        defaults: new {  controller = "Advertisement", action = "Index" },
        constraints: new { id = @"\d+", advertid = @"\d+" }
        namespaces: new string[] { "LiveChatPrototype.Mvc.Areas.Advert.Controllers" }
    );
    context.MapRoute(
        "Advert_second",
        "Advert/{controller}/{action}",
        new { controller = "AdvertAdmin", action = "Index" },
        namespaces: new string[] { "LiveChatPrototype.Mvc.Areas.Advert.Controllers" }
    );
}
```

Hope this helps